# how to make the data in the page not disappear when the page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible for data in the table not disappear when u press f5?
here is my code:

```
function Display_Start_Data(down_Time_Start) {
     console.log(downTimeStart);
     var newContent = '';

        $.each(downTimeStart.data, function (i, item) {
            newContent += Hesto.Html.StartTR(item.downTimeStart);
            newContent += Hesto.Html.CreateTD('<input type="button" value="Stop" id="btnStopEvent">');      
            newContent += Hesto.Html.CreateTD(item.CategoryName);
            newContent += Hesto.Html.CreateTD(item.StartTime);
            newContent += Hesto.Html.CreateTD(item.EndTime);
            newContent += Hesto.Html.CreateTD(item.Comments);
            newContent  = Hesto.Html.EndTR(newContent);
        });
        $('#DowntimeList').append(newContent);     
 }
```

Comment: No, unless you render it server side or run the same code again when the page is loaded.

Comment: Maybe you could use cookies.....

Comment: read about HTML5 local storage - it's useful for small amount of data

Answer (score 0):

You may save the data in the local storage of the browser but not all browsers support that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it either by using server side sessions or client side cookies. You can use Html5 local storage but it may only work on latest browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Possible via:

1. custom procedure to save/recall from cookies.
2. custom procedure to save/recall from local storage.
3. custom procedure to save/recall from server side.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and one line answer would be **No**.

You cannot save the data using jQuery. It is a job of Cache (Serverside or client side) or localStorage (HTML5; in browser). Otherwise, you'll get a new page each time the page is loaded pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>.

When the user presses F5 button. The browser sends a request to the server to load the page, the page is loaded with the content that is sent by the server. No extra data is appened to the page by the browser. That is why, no data is saved once the user presses F5.

For this purpose, developers use some other technologies in saving the user's sessions. Some of the example of what are

#### Cache

Cache is of two types, one is saved by the server. Other is saved by the client itself (client-side agent; a.k.a Browser).

You can learn this from other companies and their developer helping guides.

https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching

#### localStorage

HTML5'a API introduced a new element known as localStorage; not an element, its a plugin or what you can call a new technology. In it, you can store the data in the client-machine; computer. Which can be used once again.

Using this you can store the data; form data, in the computer and then get it back once the user presses F5.

You can learn about its API on Mozilla Developer Guide

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

browser locale storage refer this link

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_webstorage_local